# Integration of salesforce with Testlink

Tags: salesforce1-app, soap-api, integration, salesforce-id

I am working on the integration of salesforce with Testlink. I found that go2group plugin can  be used to integrate salesforce with jira. I would like to know if any plugin is available for integrating with testlink. Or please suggest me if there any API that can be used. Kindly provide instructions to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Cloudpipes](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/salesforce/testlink) which is currently in invite-only beta.

Comment: I've sent an invite to cloud pipe.But I didn't get any response yet.

Comment: It takes a while, I got mine after 2-3 days